# How to remove multiple elements from list based on another list without creating new instance?

Tags: c#, linq, except, removeall

I would like to know if its possible to remove multiple items from list based on another list **without create new list instance**?

I know its possible to use the [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) method but it does not remove the elements from the original list like the [`removeAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAll_System_Predicate__0__) does, I would have happy to use the `removeAll` but it does not have an overload for passing a list as parameter (only for `Predicate`).

Here are some references ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819577/6844481),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823245/removing-certain-elements-from-list-condition-based-on-another-list),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780671/how-to-remove-multiple-items-in-list-using-removeall-on-condition)) similar to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745616/34092) - which shows a `RemoveAll` based solution.

Comment: @pcdev Should I delete this question?  actually the questions are bit different, although one of the answers is a truly duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
list1.RemoveAll(list => list2.Contains(list));
```